# Is there any way to open a specific file using a universal Keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Is there any way to assign a keyboard shortcut to a specific file like a .txt, .bat or .exe(user created) or its shortcut, so that it can be accessed universally?

P.S. - I tried adding Shortcut key in properties(of shortcut) but it doesn't work. What I noticed is that this method works only for shortcuts of folders and applications like browsers, command prompt etc.

I work on Windows 8.1 Home(Single Language edition), if that helps...

Comment: Windows 10: Shortcut key works for any desktop shortcut.

Comment: Just a point about the name you have chosen.. many of the people here that are most likely to help you with things like this actually LIKE batch coding.  You might think it clever or true but it is not a good way to get help to create a user name that offends them. ;^)

Comment: Thanks @harrymc , It works perfectly fine now. My problem is solved, but then why do they provide the option in properties of every file of every directory if it doesn't work...

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas  Is it okay now?   ;-)

Comment: :^) AWESOME!!  I personally don't have thin skin.. but some people do.  I was just trying to give you some advice.  That is SO FUNNY.